# Model returns nothing, but running Query returns records

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
    $threads = MessageThread::whereExists(function($query) {
            $messid = '`' . env('DB_PREFIX') . 'message_threads`.`id`';

            $query->select(\DB::raw(1))
                ->from('message_thread_participants')
                ->where('message_thread_participants.message_thread_id', '=', $messid); // AND message_thread_participants.user_id = ' . $user_id);
            })  
        ->orderBy('message_threads.created_at', 'DESC')
        ->take(30)
        ->get();
```

If I print out the resulting query using DB::getQueryLog() I get the following:

> [   {
>       "query": "select * from `bd45_message_threads` where exists (select 1 from `bd45_message_thread_participants` where
>   `bd45_message_thread_participants`.`message_thread_id` = ?) order by
>   `bd45_message_threads`.`created_at` desc limit 30",
>       "bindings": [
>         "`bd45_message_threads`.`id`"
>       ],
>       "time": 1.06   } ]

And I run that query manually (substituting the binding for the ?, I get the expected 30 results..... but the code itself returns no results... I assume it's some problem between using Models and Where Exists... but it's just a guess right now.... anyone have any clue why the query would return results in Navicat or PHPMyAdmin, but the controller returns a blank array?

Comment: Sorry, the markdown on Stackoverflow played a little havoc with the backticks in my query... but I think it's still readable....

Comment: I should have also mentioned that if I take out the "Where Exists" clause, I get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but in case someone has the same problem, it must be beacause you have to use

```
->whereColumn('bd45_message_thread_participants.message_thread_id', 'bd45_message_threads.id')
```

to compare two columns values. The `->where` expects to compare a column and a value, not another column.